# Are there any good references for Request Lifecycle Hooks in Ember?

Tags: ember.js

I recently had a bug wherein a piece of code I had written in a route's afterModel hook was not working because I needed reference to the routes controller which is not available at that time. This got me started looking for resources to understand the ordering and details of the hooks present in various pieces of Ember.

The only good resource I found was a single blogpost: [Router Request Lifecycle](http://blog.trackets.com/2013/02/08/router-request-lifecycle.html) which lists:

```
- enter (private)
- activate - executed when entering the route
- deserialize (private)
- model (formely deserialize) - takes the params and returns a model which is set to the route’s currentModel
- serialize - used to generate dynamic segments in the URL from a model
- setupController - takes currentModel and sets it to the controller’s content by default
- renderTemplate - takes current controller and what model returns and renders the template
```

with an appropriate name
deactivate - executed when exiting the route (called by exit internally)
exit (private, requires call to this._super)

**While all of these hooks are mentioned in the guides disparately, there is no organized resource in the official guides which lays out the various hooks in chronological order and explains the blog post does.** Please do not just say "Read the guides"

So I'm interested to see if there are any other resources which display the chronological order of how hooks are called on view, model, controller or template setup.

Comment: The view [hook lifecycle](http://emberjs.com/guides/understanding-ember/the-view-layer/#sts=Lifecycle Hooks), as for the rest I can't seem to find them again, will update you as I look

Comment: Please do! If I can compile enough good info on this I am going to try  to make a pr on the actual docs repo and get this info included in the official docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @[teddyzeenny](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1765925/teddy-zeenny) here's a [jsbin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/basebi/2/edit) that shows what fires in what order on the model:

```
"before model"
"model"
"after model"
"activate"
"setup controller"
```